# How to use ssh-copy-id with stdin?

Tags: linux, ssh

I already know that there are other questions like this, but their answers don't help me. The suggestion in other forums was to use `sshpass` or pre install the ssh keys, but I can't use `sshpass` and I can't pre install ssh keys in the system.

I want to copy my ssh key to a remote server using stdin in `ssh-copy-id` or another method where I can pass the password by stdin using `echo`.

Something like this:

```
echo -e "1234" | ssh developer@192.168.0.1 "echo "my_key" >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

This is on a CentOS system.

Comment: What's wrong with the command you show? Doesn't that work?

Comment: When I run this comand it ask by the password.

Comment: Well yes, of course. You're setting up passwordless ssh, right? So the first time you do this, it will ask for a password.

Comment: Hang on. What are you trying to do here exactly? Is the 1234 supposed to be the ssh password?

Comment: Yes, when I try to connect to a remote server in the first time it will ask the password, but the problem is that it is not accepting the password typed in the echo command.

Comment: @terdon Yes, 1234 is the password of my remote server.

Comment: @terdon I want to connect to a remote server using stdin, I dont want to use sshpass, só Im trying to connect to the remote server using stdin and copy my ssh public key to the remote server.

Comment: Can't you [set up passwordless ssh](http://linuxproblem.org/art_9.html)? Then you don't need to deal with any of this.

Comment: This is my problem, for example in this link that you share http://linuxproblem.org/art_9.html when he connect to the remote server to create the folder ~/.ssh was asked the password of the remote host, to login and run the command, I dont want to type the password.

Comment: I want that the password to I login in a remote host be pre defined in the script like using echo as in trying to do, in order to when the remote host ask by the password, the echo command insert the password and connect automatically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115296/discussion-between-terdon-and-ziliom-brom).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the variable `SSH_ASKPASS` for that.

connect.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

pwd="mypassword"

if [ ! -t 1 ]; then
   # The output is not going to stdout, assume the invoke is from SSH_ASKPASS
   printf "%s\n" "$pwd"
   exit 0
fi

# SSH_ASKPASS will be used only if DISPLAY is defined
export DISPLAY=:0

# Set the SSH_ASKPASS program to THIS script+
export SSH_ASKPASS="$0"

# setsid is required (Run a program in a new session)
setsid ssh-copy-id user@localhost
```

Comment: What is the -t flag in if?